# Simple examples of rings from topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory

The ring $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is an interesting example of ring due to its some interesting property (namely, structure of maximal ideals).

The ring $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ of entire functions is also an interesting ring: it is integral domain.

I didn't find any example of ring arising from topology. Are there simple, interesting examples of rings arising from topology, or as collection of nice maps from a topological space to other set?

(Of course, the domains in first two examples are topological spaces as well; I would consider then other examples, which are obtained not simply taking open intervals, or open connected subsets in $\mathbb{C}$, but they arise in some funny way from topology.)

Comment: Do cohomology rings count?

Comment: It always depends on what you mean by simple. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) is an example that's given early on in Atiyah-Macdonald.